# What statistical test should I run to select "explicative" features in my dataset?

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic, neural-networks, feature-selection

I have a database with more than 500 samples with 22 quantitative features each and I would like to predict a categorical variable (0 or 1).
I am trying to fit a logistic regression model and a neural network in R using glm and the neural net package.

By selecting different features I noted that I get different results in terms of ability of my two models to predict the test set (another 500+ samples database) a +-10% in accuracy depending on how many and what features are used (using the same test set).
Essentially the models seems to get worse using more than 12 features on average but of course I cannot try all the combinations and I'd rather not use random features as a blind guess. Also the neural network seems a little bit picky on features and does not always converge (however this is a minor issue).

What tests could I run in R to select the most "explicative" features?

(By the way, is "explicative" the right terminology?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always a problem dealing with many predictor variables. Even in your logistic regression you might need to add interaction terms (if you haven't done it yet). So apart from picking the variables you have to pick interactions as well. 
I'd recommend first trying a decision tree as it does take interactions into account and automatically selects best variable combination (in terms of prediction). Check libraries "party" "rpart". 
Another solution is not picking some variables but combine all of them to create other, new, variables to use. Check PCA (principal component analysis) approach, but make sure it handles categorical variables and not only continuous.

Comment: Hi @AntoniosK, thanks for your reply, I've tried also some of the possible interaction terms however I see no major improvements (I think mainly because of the high number of possible combinantions). I am going to try with decision trees since I am not really sure on how PCA results should be interpreted, PCA is really new for me as is most of unsupervised learning methods.

Comment: PCA might improve your predictive capability, but will definitely make it impossible to interpret and create some useful simple stories to say. Logistic regression will be the best if you are interested in how each of the predictor variables affect your outcome (as the coefficient interpretation give you an idea) and the decision tree will be the best if you are interested in spotting the groups (variable combinations and splits) that maximise your outcome (as you don't have coefficients for each variable but tree branches that split variables into subsets).